# php minus past date from current date and get result in days

Tags: php, date, datetime

Im looking for the less complicated way to do the following:

```
$joinDate = "2014-05-26"
$date = date('Ymd'); //todays date
$memberFor = $joinDate - $date //This is where I need to get total number of days
```

Is there a function that can help me with this?

Comment: What is complicated here?

Comment: You have to use `strtotime()` before the calculation.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using DateTime Object for these operations

```
$joinDate = "2014-05-26";

$joinDate_obj = new DateTime($joinDate);
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $joinDate_obj->diff($now);

$diff = $interval->d ;

echo $diff; //12
```

The object `$interval` will have

```
DateInterval Object (
  [y] => 0 
  [m] => 11 
  [d] => 12 
  [h] => 12 
  [i] => 49 
  [s] => 4 
  [weekday] => 0 
  [weekday_behavior] => 0 
  [first_last_day_of] => 0 
  [invert] => 0 
  [days] => 347 
  [special_type] => 0 
  [special_amount] => 0 
  [have_weekday_relative] => 0 [have_special_relative] => 0
```

) 
So you may use for example `$interval->days` for the difference in days.

Comment: And what will the result be, for example, if there is more than 50days difference?

Comment: @Glavić $interval object will have all the data for difference so I would say just do a var_dump() and see what all you have and use them (for op), if you are specif to find the difference in days between 2 days use `$interval->days`,